# Laravel 5.2 blade views not being rendered, even though the foot view shows. Internal server error

Tags: php, laravel

I have tried every thing and even checked the whole of stack overflow.  My Laravel blade views are not being rendered.  There is an internal server error.  the default root view shows but the rest aren't.  The permissions are fine, currently 777 on all folders and files.  I'm really stuck.  What could it be?

Comment: you should add some of your code.

Comment: could be a lot of things :/ did you add the 'blade.php' extensions on your view files ? and 777 is crap, never do that on production as it's a HUGE security problem ;-)

Comment: sure, ive moved it to 775.  Yes I have got .blade.php on the extensions.  I just dont seem to know what it is.

Answer (score 0):

Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {

```
//Routes using UserController

Route::get('/welcome1ab', [
       'uses'=>'UserController@getWelcome1ab',
       'as' => 'welcome1ab',
]);

Route::post('/welcome1ab', [
       'uses'=>'UserController@postWelcome1ab',
       'as' => 'register1',
]);        

Route::get('/', [ 
       'uses'=>'UserController@getWelcome',
       'as' => 'welcome',       
]);

Route::get('/welcome1a', [
       'uses'=>'UserController@getWelcome1a',
       'as' => 'welcome1a',
]);



Controller functions:

class UserController extends Controller{

public function getWelcome1ab(Request $request){
     
     return view('welcome1ab');
}  

public function getWelcome1a(Request $request){
     
     return view('welcome1a');
} 

public function getWelcome1(Request $request){
     
     return view('welcome1');
}  
public function getWelcome(Request $request){
     
     return view('welcome');
}
```